# Frame with padding/margins (without using mdframed)

Tags: minipage, framed

I'm wondering how to add paddings in a frame (as you can see, left and right paddings are the same, but not the same as top and bottom paddings). I know it can be done using `mdframed`, but sometimes, I get parts of it not showing (eg top or left line not showing). I was told it can be done using `\fbox` and `minipage`, but I'm not sure if its possible to add paddings like this.
Thanks for your help.
[image: frame]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am sure, this can be done better without `\fbox`, but I am no `mdframed` expert. With `tcolorbox` this is very easy however. Please show us what you have done so far...

Comment: I didnt do much, i was just trying \fbox together with minipage, but couldnt make it, so i used framed (but also couldnt set those paddings), and finally mdframed (but I dont like it because of that mistake)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tcolorbox` approach -- one exaggerated example and (another) exaggerated example, to show the effects of the `top` etc. options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt,top=20pt,left=50pt,right=40pt, bottom=30pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,colback=white,colframe=black]
\begin{definition}
\blindtext
\end{definition}
\end{tcolorbox}


A tight box
\begin{tcolorbox}[boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt, bottom=0pt,arc=0pt,auto outer arc,colback=white,colframe=black]
\begin{definition}
\blindtext
\end{definition}
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]